# Loading AngularJS after other file

Tags: javascript, xml, angularjs

I have this setup with angularJS and a plugin that loads in some configuration via XML,

but the problem is that for some services I need config from that XML file, I tried loading in the angular app after the xml is loaded but it doesn't like that

then tried calling the service after the XML is loaded, but they set their url when the modules are loaded

any clue on how to let Angular wait for the xml?

waiting was like this:

```
  config.addLoadEvent(function () {
     // after xml is loaded
  });
```

Comment: Do you need that XML for angularJS services?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it by removing the ng-app

and putting inserting

```
config.addLoadEvent(function () {
    angular.bootstrap(document, ['videoDriveApp']);
});
```

so the angular get's loaded when the config is done loading